# After submit form open a view

Tags: 7, forms

I am using the custom module to create a block wich contains a form. I added this form in a node of a custom content type. When I click to submit, I want to open a view wich contains another form and I will create it in the same module.

this is my code

```
function my_module_block_info() {
$blocks['visit'] = array(
    'info' => t('Visit'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_GLOBAL
);
return $blocks;
}
function my_module_block_view($delta = '') {
$block = array();
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) && arg(2) == '') {
    $nid = arg(1);
}
switch ($delta) {
    case 'visit':
        $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('visit_project', $nid);
        break;
}
return $block;
}
function visit_project($form, &$form_state, $nid) {
$form['id'] = array(
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#value' => $nid,
);
$form['actions'] = array('#type' => 'actions');
$form['actions'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Visit'),
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('general_button')),
    '#submit' => array('_visit_project_details')
);
return $form;
}
function my_module_menu() {
$items['my-page'] = array(
    'title' => 'Title of my page',
    'page callback' => 'project_details',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
);
return $items;
}
function _visit_project_details($form_state)
{
   $form_state['redirect'] = 'my-page';
}
function project_details() {
    return '<p>ok in details of '.$_POST['id'].'</p>';
}
```

Can you help to go to **my-page** after submit form and still reading the $_POST?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code is redirecting to my-page

```
<?php

function my_module_block_info() {
$blocks['visit'] = array(
    'info' => t('Visit'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_GLOBAL
);
return $blocks;
}
function my_module_block_view($delta = '') {
$block = array();
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) && arg(2) == '') {
    $nid = arg(1);
}
switch ($delta) {
    case 'visit':
        $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('visit_project', $nid);
        break;
}
return $block;
}
function visit_project($form, &$form_state, $nid) {
$form['id'] = array(
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#value' => $nid,
);
$form['actions'] = array('#type' => 'actions');
$form['actions'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Visit'),
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('general_button')),
    //'#submit' => array('_visit_project_details')
    '#submit' => $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'],
);
$form['actions']['#submit'][] = '_visit_project_details';
return $form;
}


function my_module_menu() {
$items['my-page'] = array(
    'title' => 'Title of my page',
    'page callback' => 'project_details',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
);
return $items;
}
function _visit_project_details($form, $form_state)
{
   //$form_state['redirect'] = 'my-page';
   drupal_goto('my-page');
}
function project_details() {
    return '<p>ok in details of '.$_POST['id'].'</p>';
}
```

Comment: thank you @sivani. just $_POST['id'] is not readable after drupal_goto. I saved it in $_SESSION